# Is it possible for non-admins to see workflow tasks and comments after completion?

Tags: workflow, permissions

SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1

The Editors would like to be able to see all tasks and comments related to a workflow process, even after it has been completed. We showed the Editors the history of the workflows you can access in the admin section of the CME. This is the information they want to be able to access. Is it possible to provide them access to this without granting System Administrator permission?

We could probably develop something using the core service, but were wondering if it's possible to grant them access to see this, without having to develop a custom tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible provided these Users or the group to which they belongs to have **Workflow Management** rights as shown - this option must be checked for specific publication for the desired user/group:
[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks for that. By going to the publication, right clicking -> Properties -> 'Security' tab, we can add the user group and then select 'Workflow management' from the Rights column on the right hand side.